# Blocked because of disallowed mime type ("text/html")

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, vuejs3, vite

I am aware there are many questions regarding this topic, but after extensive looking there was only one Firebase example and it didn't cover my scenario with using hosting.

I have an app that I am currently testing in Firebase hosting, the app goes through the data retrieval process well enough with data coming in fine on first page entry.

When I go to refresh the page in order to test that the cache we are using retrieves the data properly, the entire app goes blank and I receive the errors shown below

After some looking into if similar example have already been asked, I found out that the errors in the console dont necessarily point to the actual issue, making this all the more confusing. In order to help the reader I will include the vite and firebase config files to show the project is connected fine. I will also add the index.html in my dist folder to show the .js file mentioned in the error.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

One thing I did notice while checking my cloud functions on the backend is that the function that retrieves the detail information is only hit once on the first successful load. When I refresh, it doesn't get hit again, which gives me the idea it may be something related to the router, but I haven't worked out what the issue there might be besides the docId that's passed as a prop not being available.

I am able to refresh any page where I don't pass the docId as a prop as well, but some confusion I have is I'm not able to replicate the error I'm getting on localhost. There, I am able to refresh fine anywhere without issues at all. Any idea what the problem here is? I am using Vue 3 with Vite and Firebase.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's [easy to read, copy, and search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/807126).  You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As covered by [@BrownieInMotion's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14585634) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76301968/3068190), your rewrite rule for `"source": "**"` is redirecting all non-existent files to your main `/index.html` file. Because  `./assets/index.659db071.js` does not exist on your deployed app (at time of writing, the current version is `./assets/index.2b83c04b.js`), the browser gets sent the content of `/index.html` instead (a `text/html` file). This causes the error you are seeing.

To correct your rewrite rule, so that it doesn't redirect for anything in the `/assets` folder, you should update your `firebase.json` file to the following:

```json
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**",
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "!/@(assets|images)/**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here any file in the "assets" (make sure its the same as `build.assetsDir`) or "images" (included to show how to specify multiple folders) folders won't be redirected to `/index.html` and will instead be shown your configured 404 error page.

---

Additionally, your `index.html` should probably be updated to refer to `/assets/index.****.js` instead (note missing `.` at the start) so that it always refers to `https://example.com/assets/index.****.js` instead of improperly handling nested paths such as `https://example.com/renter-team-profile/assets/index.****.js` in your error in the question. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar enough with Vite to know where the setting for this is.

Comment: I appreciate the thorough direction, Sam! Unfortunately the same behavior happened again once I rebuilt the project and redeployed. This is good direction to start with though, much appreciated!

Comment: On further inspection it looks like it builds that ```./assets/main.css``` folder path from my ```main.js``` file where i bring in the bootstrap and other css that goes with it.

Comment: @AdamBrashear I just navigated to your site and can see the fix is working as intended, however, I can also see that the second point I mentioned is still causing problems because of the relative URLs.

Comment: You were right. I removed the dot in the ```vite.config``` and it solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is your `"rewrites"`, which causes every route to be served `index.html`. Then since FireFox is nosniff by default, it fails when your resources all have content type `text/html`.

In your specific case, visit `/assets/index.659db071.js` and press CTRL+u to view source. Notice it's your `index.html` file and not the JavaScript it should be.

Comment: I went to the file and pressed CTRL + U and nothing happened. What is the process for correcting the situation?