# Title and blank page after deploying React app using Firebase Hosting and GitHub Pages

Tags: reactjs, firebase, github-pages, firebase-hosting

I've been using GH pages to host an app made using create-react-app, and now I'm trying to use Firebase for hosting.

After following the steps on various tutorials and deploying the app, the only thing that is visible is the app title in the browser tab. The screen is blank.

Here is the Firebase json file:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have tried other solutions (setting public to "build", removing the homepage attribute in the package.json file...) but nothing has worked yet.

Comment: What messages do you see in DevTools? It sounds like your `index.html` file is being served correctly, but the scripts that it tries to import have not. You may need to make a change similar to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76302372/3068190) to exclude certain directories from the rewrite rule.

Comment: For my JS, I'm getting: 
`The script at “_____/static/js/main.21aab1bb.js” was loaded while its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.`

and for my CSS it's `the stylesheet https://________/static/css/main.72111c79.css was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/html", does not is not “text/css”.`

Comment: Sounds like the `index.html` file that is being served to your browser does not match the latest build. Try forcing a hard refresh to clear your cache. If you visit those URLs in your browser, you are probably sent the content of your `index.html` file (as `text/html`) instead of the intended `.css` or `.js` files.